# What is the meaning of [[]] notation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

From the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

```
var o = new Object();
o.[[Prototype]] = Foo.prototype;
Foo.call(o);
```

What is `[[Prototype]]` exactly? I tried to find a specification for that in the documentation itself, but it's just thrown at you like that.

Comment: It's basically `__proto__` now.

Comment: To find out more I'd try reading [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) and [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/)

Comment: Following the ECMAScript standard, the notation someObject.[[Prototype]] is used to designate the prototype of someObject. This is equivalent to the JavaScript property __proto__ (now deprecated). It should not be confused with the func.prototype property of functions, which instead specifies the [[Prototype]] of all instances of the given function. Since ECMAScript 6, the [[Prototype]] is accessed using the accessors Object.getPrototypeOf() and Object.setPrototypeOf(). 
**Referred from:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: They explain it in the docs you linked. They're using it as a notation to refer to the object(s) from which an object inherits.

Comment: @NikhileshShivarathri ah ok, so it's just notation, not actual code.

Comment: @squint: ok so it has no language value, it's just for documentation.

Comment: Yep, exactly. It's notation used in the spec, or at least it used to be. Not sure about the most recent versions.